# Derivation of the braking torque induced by Eddy current in a rotating disc

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, torque

This question was cross-posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4579870/407996), but I didn't receive an answer. So, I thought that, maybe, there was a missing physics assumption, which makes me post the same question here.

In the article [On Eddy Currents in a Rotating Disk](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6436528), the function `U` is defined as the stream function of the eddy current flowing through a rotating disc of radius `r`.

Starting from Eq. (20),

$$
U = \frac{\omega r c b \gamma \Phi \sin{\theta}}{2\pi} \left(1 - \frac{A^2 a^2}{c^2 r^2 + A^4 - 2 r c A^2 \cos{\theta}} \right)
$$

I am a mechanical engineer, so I would like to understand, **in the simplest way**, how the symbolic definite integration with respect to θ in the following definition of the torque `T`

$$
T = \frac{\Phi}{\pi a^2} \int_{c-a}^{c+a} \int_{-\theta_1}^{\theta_1} r \frac{\partial U}{\partial r} r dr d\theta
$$

led to

$$
T = \frac{\omega c b \gamma \Phi^2}{\pi^2 a^4} \times \int_{c-a}^{c+a} 
\left( r^2 \sin{\theta_1} - \frac{a^2 A^2 r^2 \sin{\theta_1}}{c^2 r^2 + A^4 - 2 A^2 r c \cos{\theta_1}} \right) dr
$$

where $\theta_1$ and $r$ are connected by the relation $r^2 + c^2 — 2 r c \cos{\theta_1} = a^2$.

P.S. I tried to symbolically evaluate the integration with respect to $\theta$ using the Wolfram Engine, and it gives me a numeric value of zero, not the reported answer above.

Answer (score 1):

First off, to make things more simple, I would integrate by parts in $r$:
$$
T = \frac{\Phi}{\pi a^2}\left(\int_{-\theta_1}^{\theta_1}d\theta [Ur^2]_{c-a}^{c+a}-\int_{c-a}^{c+a}dr 2r \int_{-\theta_1}^{\theta_1}d\theta U \right)
$$
so you just need to perform at fixed $r$ the integral:
$$
\int_{-\theta_1}^{\theta_1}d\theta U 
$$
this is done by the change of variables $\theta \to z=\cos \theta$ since schematically:
$$
U = A\sin\theta \left(1-\frac{B}{C-\cos \theta}\right) \\
\int d\theta = \int dz A \left(1-\frac{B}{C-z}\right) \\
=[A(z +B\ln(C-z))]
$$
with $A,B,C$ $r$ dependent constants. After calculating the antiderivative, you just need to evaluate at the boundaries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I highly appreciate your help. However, in view of my poor mathematics level, I can't grasp the intermediate steps you omitted in your beautiful answer. So, if this wouldn't bother I would be grateful to learn these steps in more detail. I know this is out of the scope of this site, but I am just trying my luck :)